# How to remove fastclick from a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fastclick.js

I am using [fast click](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) and I am applying it to the body by:

```
FastClick.attach(document.body);
```

How do I not apply it to an element like:

```
<div class="item">My El</div> -- Do not apply fastclick to this element
```

**UPDATE**

[Missed the doc which tells how to](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick#advanced)

Comment: It's right there in the [readme](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick#advanced) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the class "needsclick" to an element, then fastclick won't try and do its special magic.

```
<div class="item needsclick">My El</div>
```

Comment: did not get that, you mean that if I apply that class fast click will be applied or not applied?

Comment: @rob.m Yes - add the class "needsclick" (as in my update to the answer).  It's documented in the fastclick Readme on the github page, in "Advanced Usage".